# Where can I find the applied data science research papers?

Tags: machine-learning, research, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to find conferences that have applied data science papers published. I'm only interested in top ranked conferences. And I notice quite a number of them are quite theoretical, e.g. IJAI, NIPS, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for conferences that focus on applied data science and have a high ranking, there are several options you can consider. While it's true that some conferences may have a more theoretical emphasis, there are also reputable conferences that highlight practical and applied aspects of data science. Here are a few suggestions:

1. ACM SIGKDD Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining (KDD): KDD is one of the premier conferences in data mining and knowledge discovery. It covers a wide range of topics including applied data science, machine learning, data mining, and big data analytics.
2. IEEE International Conference on Data Mining (ICDM): ICDM is another top conference in the field of data mining. It brings together researchers and practitioners to discuss the latest advancements in data mining and its applications.
3. International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML): While ICML does have a theoretical focus, it also accepts and features applied data science papers. It is a leading conference in the machine learning community and covers a broad range of topics.
4. International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence (IJCAI): IJCAI is a prestigious conference in the field of artificial intelligence. While it does include theoretical research, it also accepts and showcases applied data science papers.
5. International Conference on Data Science and Advanced Analytics (DSAA): DSAA focuses specifically on data science and advanced analytics. It welcomes submissions related to practical applications, data-driven solutions, and real-world case studies.

These conferences are known for their rigorous review process and attract top researchers and practitioners in the field. Keep in mind that acceptance rates for these conferences can be highly competitive, so ensure that your work aligns well with the conference's scope and requirements.

Additionally, you can also explore domain-specific conferences in areas such as healthcare, finance, or industry-specific data science conferences. These conferences often highlight applied research and real-world applications within their respective domains.

Remember to check the websites of these conferences for the most up-to-date information on submission deadlines, conference dates, and paper requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Open Data Science Conference [ODSC](https://odsc.com/) is what you are looking for - industry leaders present some tools that they use in their work. The ones you've listed are research oriented, the material presented there comes mostly from research (R&D) departments from companies.

There are many other conferences as well, but IMO they are technology specific, e.g., like the Apache Flink Forward [conference](https://www.flink-forward.org/seattle-2023). You can search for the technology you are interested in and might find some events.

Also, the Journal of Open Source Software [JOSS](https://joss.theoj.org/) might be of interest.